# ts file not playing in android tablet

Tags: android

I am trying to play a file i have recorded. The file plays well in vlc(linux pc) and in Moboplayer(android tablet). While using the default player in the android tablet it shows this in logcat.

```
I/ActivityManager(  201): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.mymediaplayer/.MyVideoView bnds=[656,246][752,342]} from pid 417
I/System.out(20286): MyVideoView.onCreate()
I/System.out(20286): MyVideoView.onResume()
V/TabletStatusBar(  281): setLightsOn(true)
I/AwesomePlayer(  141): setDataSource_l('/sdcard/video/TunerOut.ts')
I/avc_utils(  141): found AVC codec config (720 x 480, Baseline-profile level 3.1)
I/MPEG2TSExtractor(  141): haveAudio=1, haveVideo=1
E/OMXCodec(  141): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER'
E/OMXCodec(  141): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.Nvidia.h264.decode'
E/OMXCodec(  141): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.qcom.7x30.video.decoder.avc'
E/OMXCodec(  141): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc'
E/OMXCodec(  141): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.TI.Video.Decoder'
E/OMXCodec(  141): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder'
E/OMXCodec(  141): Successfully allocated OMX node 'OMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder'
I/OMXCodec(  141): [OMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder] AVC profile = 66 (Baseline), level = 31
E/OMXCodec(  141): [OMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder] Video O/P format.eColorFormat 0x40b452b1
I/OMXCodec(  141): [OMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder] video dimensions are 720 x 480
D/OpenGLRenderer(  417): Flushing caches (mode 1)
I/ActivityManager(  201): Displayed com.example.mymediaplayer/.MyVideoView: +323ms
W/InputManagerService(  201): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4106dc38 (uid=10036 pid=20503)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20503): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
E/OMXCodec(  141): Attempting to allocate OMX node 'OMX.Nvidia.mp2.decoder'
**E/MediaPlayer(20286): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(20286): Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView(20286): Error: 1,-2147483648**
D/OpenGLRenderer(  417): Flushing caches (mode 0)
W/InputManagerService(  201): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41033300
D/AudioHardware(  141): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
```

what is error 1,-2147483648

Answer (score 0):

I just had that error too. The reason (in my case) was that the mp3 has the wrong format, i.e.

```
MPEG ADTS, layer II, v1, 192 kbps, 44.1 kHz, Stereo
```

while a "good" mp3 has this format:

```
MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1, 128 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
```